# Is possible use proxxy in client side in nuxt3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

The nuxt use useFetch for get data when component is mounted. I need use proxxy in this moment, taking into account that useFetch only renders on the client side.

configuration proxxy in nuxt.config that works

```
nitro: {
        devProxy: {
            "/api": {
                target: process.env.API_URL,
                changeOrigin: true,
                prependPath: true,
            }
        }
    }
```

function

````
const token = useCookie('token')
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.value}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
  // função não roda no server, com isso não é possivel usar o proxy
  const { data: clubes, error } = await useFetch(`/api/club`, {headers: headers})
```
 in functions that not need run in client side function, what resolve ?
````